# Set text from sqlite rows in Pyqt textbrowser

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, pyqt5

I need a way to set some rows from sqlite.db to pyqt textbrowser,But the problem is that it just put the last row.

```
cur = conn.cursor()
conn.text_factory = str
cur.execute(" SELECT text FROM Translation WHERE priority = ?", (m,))
for row in cur:
    print('{0}'.format(row[0]))
    self.SearchResults.setPlainText('{0}'.format(m))
```

I used pandas but,

```
query = "SELECT text FROM Translation WHERE priority=2;"

df = pd.read_sql_query(query,conn)
 self.SearchResults.setPlainText('{0}'.format(df['text']))
```

This is not what I want.And this:

```
cur = conn.cursor()
conn.text_factory = str
cur.execute(" SELECT text FROM Translation WHERE priority = ?", (m,))
    all_rows=cur.fetchall()

    self.SearchResults.setPlainText('{0}'.format(all_rows))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first code you are replacing the text every time you iterate, the solution is to use `append()`

```
cur = conn.cursor()
conn.text_factory = str
cur.execute(" SELECT text FROM Translation WHERE priority = ?", (m,))

self.SearchResults.clear() # clear previous text

for row in cur:
    self.SearchResults.append('{0}'.format(str(row[0])))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot eyllanesc.I didn't know about that